# Replace all dead links with archive.org link

Tags: feature-request, broken-link

How about a script which replaces all dead links (404, 302) with a link to archive.org as of the date the post was created, including a link to the donate page? Like this:

[image: screenshot of edit which replaces dead link with an archive.org version]

It would help both Stack Overflow and the Internet Archive at the same time.

Comment: how would it help the Archive?

Comment: 302 links aren't dead, they're just moved and redirect automatically to the new page. So I don't see any reason to replace 302 links with a link to archive.org. But for 404 links I agree that it can be useful.

Comment: @Shog9 Because it would have a link to the donate page and demonstrate the need for archive.org. \@Donald Duck - True but sometimes they are redirected to the home page and not the new location for the article. That is definitely harder to detect.

Comment: Issues:  Finding the right link on archive.org.  Not every dead link will have an entry on archive.org.  There's the possibility that a 404 error is transient (due to system upgrades, maintenance, hardware problems, configuration problems, etc).  And having a donate link would open a can of worms that shouldn't be opened.

Comment: I've replaced a fair number of dead links with archive.org links.  Never once got the impression that doing so did not require the massively parallel computing machine I got between my ears.

Comment: Agreed with most of points. For sure there's a kindly designed algorithm to deal with. Let's say an active db that replaces dead links, a worker that ensures that those dead links where not just temporal. Even more, a simple-dead "icon" near to links that let's you find that link in archive without delete it for real. I think that's a good idea to replace links programatically, done right of course.

Answer (score 5):

First off, 302 links are moved and still work in some instances.

Secondly, not all 404 links are present on archive.org and sometimes, it makes no sense to replace them with archive.org because there are better alternatives (like a library doc that has moved but the original domain has been sold or shut down instead of redirecting).

I think using archive.org in cases where it is merited is generally useful, but it should be a distinction made by a human as to when it is to be used.

Comment: Then why not a per link user-vote to be replaced? This way is user based decision, human being. This way we remove out the need of superflous comments suggesting archive.org links in replacemente for dead ones.